# Delphi - Connecting and logging in to a webpage

Tags: delphi, authentication, indy

**EDIT**
There has been quite a development. The current problem is this:

> I compared requests sent from a browser and sent from my app. There have been some differences and I managed to correct most of them. Some are still unfixed, since I haven't figured it out how yet. I am using INDY.

- How can i send (or add) cookies into the request?

  I tried this:`IdHTTP.CookieManager.AddCookie('bakatheme=BrectanTheme',IdHTTP1.URL)` but it doesn't work. Also, in INDY help they say that it is supposed to be AddCookie(String, String), but my Delphi only accept (String, TIdURI) - I am not sure if it is the right URI I am calling.
- In the Headers I have this code: `AcceptEncoding:='gzip,deflate,sdch';` yet when I parse the outgoing request, it states this: `AcceptEncoding:gzip,deflate,sdch,identity`but I am certain I don't have "identity" anywhere in the code.

Those are the two things in which my request differs from the browser's. Now, I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error at return, can it be caused by the lack of cookies or the second thing?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can login to a site and maintain session between calls with many component suites, including INDY.  I just don't understand what is your question here, it looks like you have no idea how the web works.  If you don't, start learning about HTTP post and get verbs, how different sites manages sessions, and how different sites manages login and sessions to track users.  Learn how to use a sniffer and see how raw data go and comes between a browser and your preferred site before trying to do this at a low level using any programming language.

Comment: I've managed to log in, please see the edited post.

Comment: @Magicmaster What do you see posted to that page in the sniffer when you login in the site from any browser?

Comment: Hello, please read the top of the post. It is more of a Delphi/Indy problem now I guess though.

Comment: @Magic The question is a mess.. I think you have to start from the beginning with it.  I don't think the form in which it is expressed is understandable to someone coming to this question for the first time right now.  This site is not only about asking questions between two or three persons.. it is about making this content available and understandable to anyone on the Internet interested on the topic.  Think about it and re-structure it to make it understandable.  As for your problem, a 500 status implies: or the server is having trouble at the time or your request is really malformed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Lets comment:

> How can i send (or add) cookies into the request?

You should not do that. Indy handles this for you (but if really want to, there is a `TidCookieManager`). But it seems to me that you dont know how cookies work. Its not a thing you can add to a request. It cames from the server and it identifies you.

> In the Headers I have this code: AcceptEncoding:='gzip,deflate,sdch';

AcceptEnconding tells to the server that it can compact the response using those algorithms. Indy supports `gzip,deflate,sdch,identity` and indy is updating que header request to add the one you forgot to put.

You should take a look at those links to learn how http works:

[W3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't exactly tried it myself but here's an example I found about website login using indy
http://www.ciuly.com/delphi/indy/persistent-login-example-for-geocacheing-no-ssl/